# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidPrefix' of undefined {}

Tags: node, tezos-client, tezos-signer, taquito, tezos-base

```
var Tezos = taquito.Tezos;
            Tezos.setProvider({rpc: 'https://carthagenet.SmartPy.io', signer: new taquitoTezbridgeSigner.TezBridgeSigner()})

            const amount = 1;
            const address = 'tz1NCsFxfRarXUYG1BAXEFMC7JFpykaRZBah';
            console.log(`Transfering ${amount} ꜩ to ${address}...`);
            Tezos.contract.transfer({ to: address, amount: amount })
            .then(op => {
                console.log(`Waiting for ${op.hash} to be confirmed...`);
                return op.confirmation(1).then(() => op.hash);
            })
            .then(hash => console.log(`Operation injected: https://carthagenet.tzstats.com/${hash}`))
            .catch(error => console.log(`Error: ${error} ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`));
```

when I ever I try to run this block of code i am getting this error and not being able to confirm transaction can my senior help where I am doing wrong thank you

[image]
[image]